# Testing visual lay-out and concept of interfaces on users before really starting development?

Tags: conceptualization, interface-design, user-experience, layout

This is essentially about lay-out and visual structure, and using a couple of more or less random people to *help thinking* ("Random" people can mean someone passing your office, your neighbour, cousin, boyfriend).

Building interfaces is a tricky business. All the wonderful designs in our heads are sparkly and dripping diamonds of course, but when it comes down to it, it is about how the users interact with it that will tell wether it is a success or not.

I know some people use video and eye-tracking in analysing interfaces and user interaction; that is not the level I am talking about. What I am after is simple user testing long *before* a system is rolled out. Quick and dirty they call it: user testing from very early on. It is mainly a tool to make *you* think, and ensure you have considered as much as possible.

The benefits are many; some glaring blunders might be sorted early, some of the users input can of course also be ignored. But it is always better to *know* you are ignoring something, than to *not know*. It is all about informed, intelligent choices.

1. One that I have used sometimes is what I call the post-it note game. For structural visual architecture: you give people a bunch of post-its with key words written on them, and ask them to sort them. It is also helpful to get them to sort the post-its *on* a piece of paper/wall, and pretend that it is the application. It could be functionality, menue-points, keywords. Often, some interesting anomalies crop up, that helps a quick rethink. Sometimes the fact that the guinea pig does not know *where or how* to categorise and place something, is a useful hint.
2. Another one is making a *very* primitive sketch, preferably on a whiteboard. It is important that this is  something that does not looks remotely finished, and a long way from the digital product. Simple, primitive boxes for content, buttons and other elements. Tell the guinea pigs what the application will be all about, give them a list of keywords, and ask them to write in *where* the various functionality should be visually placed. They should also be free to add things that they feel are missing. Let people fiddle as much as they want with it.

(In my experience, wireframes and mockups are rarely that helpful. It might make the designer feel that she is doing something, but a lot of people do not quite grasp the fact that they are *ideas*, not products)

**My question is:** what other methods have you used, that proved helpful? I would be very much interested in tools, methods and experiments that have given interesting and unexpected results, other ways of pestering users way before coding and colour-schemes comes into it.

Comment: This question belongs on and is possibly answered on http://ux.stackexchange.com - See: http://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=methods+for+testing

Comment: http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/940/se-graphic-design-appropriate-for-interface-design-review

Answer (score 3):

## Build a simple interactive prototype

I like to work with the developers from the start to make sure we're exploiting every possible advantage. Since we're already collaborating, building a rough prototype is no sweat.

I've also worked with simple image-based prototypes but there's too much hand holding and explanation. The user never gets immersed.

Comment: If "working with the developers" at this stage isn't an option it's also possible to make a simple "do people see the right link" testable architecture in an interactive PDF in Indesign: just have elements link to literal pages in the PDF instead of web pages. There are also thousands of (mostly paid) wireframe prototyping tools.

Answer (score 2):

This won't be popular, but I'd say taking an enormous dose of empathy pills and going over paper sketches with an open mind is the best way to do this. Many chefs spoil the broth.

An interface should communicate its intention and personality, be consistent and learnable from an intuitive base point that understands the user's intentions within the applications abilities and aspirations. There's only one person able to best do that... the designer.

Everyone else is vision challenged by an incomplete perspective of what it is, and dominated by their own self interest and ego.